# PHP's file_exists() will not work for me?

Tags: php, file-exists

For some reason this PHP code below will not work, I can not figure it out.

It is very strange, 
file_exists does not seem to see that the image does exist, I have checked to make sure a good file path is being inserted into the file_exists function and it is still acting up

If I change file_exists to !file_exists it will return an images that exist and ones that do not exist

```
define('SITE_PATH2', 'http://localhost/');

$noimg = SITE_PATH2. 'images/userphoto/noimagesmall.jpg';
$thumb_name = 'http://localhost/images/userphoto/1/2/2/59874a886a0356abc1_thumb9.jpg';
if (file_exists($thumb_name)) {
    $img_name = $thumb_name;
}else{
    $img_name = $noimg;
}
echo $img_name;
```

Comment: Take a note here, if it may help someone.

I use command with same user  to check a file exists works well, while not works from the browser(php-fpm). 

I've checked related config in php.ini, php-fpm.conf, www.conf, even do modification, but not works.

At last I found the config in nginx fastcgi.conf, which will overwrite the config in php.

/usr/local/nginx/conf/fastcgi.conf
`fastcgi_param PHP_ADMIN_VALUE "open_basedir=$document_root/:/tmp/:/proc/:/data/www/";`

Answer (score 104, accepted):

`file_exists()` needs to use a file path on the hard drive, not a URL.  So you should have something more like:

```
$thumb_name = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'images/userphoto/1/2/2/59874a886a0356abc1_thumb9.jpg';
if(file_exists($thumb_name)) {
    some_code
}
```

https://www.php.net/file_exists

Comment: $_SERVER['CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT'] would work if your alias is not under your document root, in which case $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] will fail

Comment: I was aware of the file path/url that gets most people. But if you are still having an issue, don't forget to check basic things, for example, I was using an alias for the path in my framework but forgot to resolve the alias to the actual path in the check.

Answer (score 9):

[docs](http://docs.php.net/file_exists) say:

> As of PHP 5.0.0, this function can also be used with **some** URL wrappers. Refer to [List of Supported Protocols/Wrappers](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php) for a listing of which wrappers support [`stat()`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.stat.php) family of functionality.

Comment: I don't believe HTTP/HTTPS are on the list of stat() supported protocols per the docs - just some "goofier" stuff like php://memory.

Answer (score 8):

[`file_exists`](http://docs.php.net/file_exists) does only work on the local file system.

So try this if you’re using *localhost*:

```
$thumb_name = 'images/userphoto/1/2/2/59874a886a0356abc1_thumb9.jpg';
if (file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$thumb_name)) {
    $img_name = SITE_PATH2.$thumb_name;
} else {
    $img_name = $noimg;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you enabled the option which allows you to use external URLs? You can set it in php.ini:

```
allow_url_fopen = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to write the file path like `"file:///C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/xyz/Desktop/clip_image001.jpg"`.

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php

did you check the comments below?

Just reading parts of it, but there seem to be several issues.

Caching may be a problem. 
When opening FTP urls it always returns true (they say in the comments)
...

Answer (score 0):

Try Below one. Its working for me

```
define('SITE_PATH2', 'http://localhost/');
$noimg = SITE_PATH2. 'images/userphoto/noimagesmall.jpg';
$thumb_name = 'http://localhost/images/userphoto/1/2/2/59874a886a0356abc1_thumb9.jpg';

if ($fileopen = @fopen($thumb_name)) {
    $img_name = $thumb_name;
    fclose($fileopen);
}else{
    $img_name = $noimg;
}
echo $img_name;
```