# check if url exists in php

Tags: php, file-exists

```
if (!(file_exists(http://example.com/images/thumbnail_1286954822.jpg))) {   
$filefound = '0';                         
}
```

why won't this work?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/981954/how-can-one-check-to-see-if-a-remote-file-exists-using-php

Answer (score 90, accepted):

```
if (!file_exists('http://example.com/images/thumbnail_1286954822.jpg')) {   
$filefound = '0';
}
```

Comment: if (!file_exists($base_url.'images/thumbnail_1286954822.jpg')) {   
$filefound = '0';                         
} it's like this actually sorry.

Comment: @anonymous actually it's not like this sorry, you didn't ask for $base_url + images/thumbnail_1286954822.jpg you asked for http:// mysite com/images/thumbnail_1286954822.jpg

Answer (score 36):

1. The function expects a string.
2. `file_exists()` does not work properly with HTTP URLs.

Comment: Do you have any solution for that?

Answer (score 20):

**file_exists** checks whether a file exist in the specified path or not.

Syntax:

```
file_exists ( string $filename )
```

Returns `TRUE` if the file or directory specified by filename exists; `FALSE` otherwise.

```
$filename = BASE_DIR."images/a/test.jpg";
if (file_exists($filename)){
    echo "File exist.";
}else{
    echo "File does not exist.";
}
```

Another alternative method you can use getimagesize(), it will return 0(zero) if file/directory is not available in the specified path.

```
if (@getimagesize($filename)) {...}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can also use `PHP` [get_headers()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php) function.

Example:

```
function check_file_exists_here($url){
   $result=get_headers($url);
   return stripos($result[0],"200 OK")?true:false; //check if $result[0] has 200 OK
}

if(check_file_exists_here("http://www.mywebsite.com/file.pdf"))
   echo "This file exists";
else
   echo "This file does not exist";
```

Comment: For me,  file_exists() didn't work.  I am trying to locate a PDF file.  But your solution worked. Thanks.  Do you know why file_exists() didn't work for me?

Comment: It depends on the code. https://stackoverflow.com/q/1287837/4366303 - this might answer you

Comment: A one liner `if(stripos(get_headers($file)[0],'200 OK'))`

Answer (score 6):

Based on your comment to Haim, is this a file on your own server? If so, you need to use the file system path, not url (e.g. `file_exists( '/path/to/images/thumbnail.jpg' )`).

Answer (score 3):

for me also the file_exists() function is not working properly. So I got this alternative solution. Hope this one help someone

```
$path = 'http://localhost/admin/public/upload/video_thumbnail/thumbnail_1564385519_0.png';

    if (@GetImageSize($path)) {
        echo 'File exits';
    } else {
        echo "File doesn't exits";
    }
```

Comment: @Nguaial

 The getimagesize() function will determine the size of any supported given image file and return the dimensions along with the file type and a height/width text string to be used inside a normal HTML IMG tag and the correspondent HTTP content type.

Answer (score 2):

Check code below

```
if ($user->image) {
        $filename = "images/" . $user->image;
        if (file_exists($filename)) {
            echo '<br />';
            echo "File exist.";
        } else {
            echo '<br />';
            echo "File does not exist.";
        }
    }
```