# How can I use PHP in my formhandler to see if image file entered into form is already in my filesystem

Tags: php, filesystems, file-exists

Here is the code I have for that, but it never returns true.

```
    $image = $_FILES['image'];

    $filename = $image['name'];
    $filepathname = "/$membername/"."$filename";

    if (file_exists($filepathname)) {
       throw new Exception('Image already exists');
    }
```

Comment: Search "relative path": http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=relative+path&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8

Comment: Also you don't want to use user-supplied values directly for any path operations. Filter, at least `basename`.

Comment: Why do you think it should return true for you?  Does `file_exists($knownExistingFilename)` return true?  Does `knownExistingFilename` match the value of `filepathname` above?

Answer (score 0):

Does "$membername" contain the $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] path?

read more @ [PHP's file_exists() will not work for me?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287837/phps-file-exists-will-not-work-for-me)

(if it does contain the $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] then you may want to check the file permission - assuming that you are using LAMP)