# File_exists failing for some files

Tags: php

`file_exists` is working for some files and not others.

To illustrate I'll limit it to two files:

> Image1.png
>
> Image2.png

Running `file_exists("Image1.png")` works, however running `file_exists("Image2.png")` fails.

Both files have the same permissions. A copy of `Image1.png` named `ImageA.png` will return the right result, a newly created file will fail.

This is on a Windows server. I had copied the files from a linux server. I installed cygwin and `chmod`ed everything to 755 just in case... same result.

Any ideas?

Comment: Show your *code*... or it didn't happen.

Comment: You aren't going to get answers if you don't show your code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I thought it didn't apply to me but it turns out it was file permissions. I had to go into the advanced windows file permissions and get them set.

If you bump into this along with thousands of others and think it's not file permissions and that you've checked them...go check them again.

Answer (score 0):

Returns TRUE if the file or directory specified by filename exists; FALSE otherwise.file_exists() needs to use a file path

```
<?php
$filename = '/path/to/image2.png';


if (file_exists($filename)) {
echo "The file $filename exists";
} else {
    echo "The file $filename does not exist";
}

?>
```

more REF :http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php

[PHP's file_exists() will not work for me?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287837/phps-file-exists-will-not-work-for-me)